# No provisioning profiles showing up

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm a developer and I'm currently trying to take a Ionic/Cordova application and bring it to iOS devices. It works fine on Android and it's on the playstore so that works. On iOS though, I've been having trouble archiving and building it as there is a weird error. No provisioning profiles are showing up at all! I've added my Apple Developer account and I have set up all the necessary certification. Here's what the provisioning profile screen looks like

[image: My Apple thing]

Does anyone know why it's like this?

Comment: Have you created provisioning profile in Apple Developer account?

Comment: try removing the account and adding it again, quit xcode and restart, I have faced the same problem once but it worked eventually like this :(

Comment: holy crap, it worked thanks!